# Split lib_main was defined multiple times

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

**Split lib_main was defined multiple times**

In "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3" build success,
But the errors that occur in the "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5".

[image: console error]

---

finally instant run work!! com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha8 and gradle.properties "org.gradle.jvmargs = -Xmx8g" was resolved to change.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem. Are you using product flavors, and applicationIdSuffix by chance?

Comment: Unfortunately, do not using "product flavors" and "applicationIdSuffix". but using "MultiDex".

Comment: same error here, disabling instant run helps. Happens only for devices that are run Android 6. 
Android Studio 2.0 5 
Using applicationIdSuffix, MultiDex, Not using product flavour

Comment: @Happydev Any way to avoid this error?

Comment: @Happydev Solved by disabling instantrun!

Comment: I have build variants and multidex, disabling InstaRun did the trick.

Comment: @Happydev - you should get the points for the right answer. Post it and so we can upvote it :-)

Comment: @bkurzius it does not seams like an solution to me, whole point of update was instant run. I hoped someone will find something like remove some library or plugin... because instant run works awesome on Marshmallow on another project.

Comment: @Happydev - for what its worth I still think you have the right answer to this particular question - its not the ideal solution but it is the only way I have been able to resolve this error so far...

Answer (score 103, accepted):

For those who wonder what InstantRun is (first setting in the picture):
[image]

And yes disabling that setting fixes the issue.

**Edit 01/19/16**

'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6' was released three days ago. Using that new version, the "Split lib_main was defined multiple times" error is gone and installation of the app succeeds but now I get a runtime error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.onegravity.k10.pro2-2/base.apk",
zip file "/data/app/com.onegravity.k10.pro2-/split_lib_main.apk"]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.onegravity.k10.pro2-2/base.apk",
zip file "/data/app/com.onegravity.k10.pro2-2/split_lib_main.apk"]

Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location
/data/app/com.onegravity.k10.pro2-2/base.apk

Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication
```

Turning off instant run eliminates that error.
Let's wait for com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha7...

**Edit 01/25/16**

'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha7' was released two days ago.

Getting the same exception as with 2.0.0-alpha6

Comment: well I guess that kind of defeated the whole point of my updating this morning :-/

Comment: I seem to spend more and more time fighting the build system. It's as if Android development becomes more and more build/deployment oriented and less coding...
Pity really because I like the flexibility of the Gradle build system.

Comment: well if they can nail instant run it would be worth the pain but so far my experience with it has not been good :-(

Comment: Even in other apps that run with instant run I had to turn it off. There are  too many cases the instant run just doesn't work. Still alpha I guess...

Comment: Thanks .. I was getting this on stable ver 2.3.1

Comment: Even wiping the data on the simulator didn't fix this problem, but disabling InstantRun did.  A shame, too, I was beginning to like InstantRun before it went all psycho on me.

Comment: This worked, I had an issue when I moved where my app was located on my PC and this fix worked immediately.

Answer (score 163):

Just **delete** `build` **folder** of `app`module and **Rebuild** the project!

This will fix the issue!.

Comment: Worked! Just rebuild and rebooting AVD didn't help!

Comment: Shouldn't "invalidate caches and restart" also invalidate the build? Because clearly it doesn't work on this case

Comment: Disabling is not the preferred way. No need to delete 'build' folder. Just **Rebuild** the project.

Answer (score 50):

I ran into this issue after refactoring and changing app name in gradle.  Following AskQ's lead, I rebuilt the project (following a slightly different path):

`Build`-> `Clean Project`

followed by

`Build`-> `Rebuild Project`

Solved the issue

Answer (score 11):

**Recovery:**

Deleting the (projectFolder)/app/**build** folder and re-building worked for me.  (as answered by @AskQ)

I wonder if **Build > Clean Project** would have worked as well; from the Android Studio GUI menus.

**Avoidance:**

In my case the problem seems to have occurred because I had copy pasted a project, so 2 projects had the same name.
There are like other causes too, learning what they are can help users avoid this concern.

Comment: I had the same error and after Clean Projekt the app worked again

Comment: A full clean/rebuild worked for me as well. Restarted the connected device in between for good measure.

Answer (score 3):

It might happen because of your package name is in uppercase, so you must change it back to lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

Android studio 2.3.3 
It worked for me after disabling Instant run in settings...

Go to **Settings**-> **Build,Execution and Development**-> **Instant Run -> Uncheck** 
*Enable Instant Run to hotswap* then clean project and Rebuild your project again!!

Comment: Disabling Instant run in settings also worked for me.