# Error installing split apks: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio is not pushing my APK into a physical Nexus 5X with Marshmallow (6.0.1).

This is the output and the error:

```
01/15 01:51:48: Launching mobile
$ adb install-multiple -r /Users/MyUser/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/mobile/build/outputs/apk/mobile-development-debug-unaligned.apk /Users/MyUser/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/mobile/build/intermediates/split-apk/development/debug/main.apk /Users/MyUser/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/mobile/build/intermediates/split-apk/development/debug/main.apk 

Error installing split apks: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Split lib_main was defined multiple times
Error during launch
```

Details:

defaultConfig:
minSdkVersion 9
targetSdkVersion 23
multiDexEnabled true

2 buildTypes: debug and release

2 productFlavors: development and production

dexOptions: 
incremental false
preDexLibraries = false
jumboMode = true
javaMaxHeapSize "4096M"

I'm using the latest Android Studio 2.0 Preview 5 (http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio20preview5available).

Gradle: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

And the build tools are: 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5'.

Is there a way to tell Android Studio no to use install-multiple to install the apk?

**UPDATE (01/15/2016 2:26 AM EST):**

The issue doesn't happen when running the app on a Galaxy Nexus emulator with Jelly Bean (4.3.1) nor a physical Samsung Galaxy S with Gingerbread (2.3.6).

**UPDATE (01/15/2016 11:30 AM EST):**

Ran the app on a Nexus 5 with KitKat (4.4.4) and it works just fine.

Comment: Are you using the NDK?

Comment: No @andresperezl, not using NDK. The curious thing is that the issue doesn't happen with a Galaxy Nexus emulator with Jelly Bean nor a physical Samsung Galaxy S with Gingerbread.

Comment: On which device and Android version you are running this app?

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803518/split-lib-main-was-defined-multiple-times

Comment: @RacZo disable instant run.

Comment: I disabled instant run in the Android Studio Preferences and still have the same issue.

Comment: Tor Norbye from Google replied to me via Twitter saying they're fixing it (https://twitter.com/tornorbye/status/688110661931368449), so I guess we will have to wait a bit.

Answer (score 11):

This should be fixed in in 2.0.0-alpha6, now available. https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system

Comment: Woah! That was fast! Thank you!

Comment: The fix seems to work and after a cleaning and rebuilding the project using 2.0.0-alpha6, Android Studio is pushing the APK to a Nexus 5X with Marshmallow, a Nexus 5 with KitKat,  a simulator with Jelly Bean and Samsung Galaxy S with Gingerbread as  2.0.0-alpha3. To make it work on the Nexus 5X, I had to clear the cache of the app, uninstall it and restart the device (if I just tried to replace the old APK by hitting run, it wouldn't work and would show lots of errors about bootstrap classes inside the APK). Thanks again!

Comment: alpha6 fixed that one issue but I had another when I tried to run the app. So disabling Instant Run was the only solution for me :-(

Comment: I'm using the NDK, preview6, alpha6 plugin and got INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: /data/app/vmdl1312093572.tmp/1_main version code 2005 inconsistent with 8002005.
Please help!

Comment: I am on alpha8. Still see this

Comment: @ChadBingham same here.

Answer (score 5):

There seem to be multiple issues with the new Gradle Plugins - both with alpha5 and alpha6. But it looks like if all else fails you need to disable Instant Run. For me this particular error was resolved by using alpha6 as @Tor Norbye indicated above -- but then I had this error instead [https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195044](http://Unable%20to%20instantiate%20application%20com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication:%20java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:%20Didn't%20find%20class%20%22com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication)

Instant Run will be a pretty cool feature when they work out the kinks!

Answer (score 0):

I just faced similar issue in Android Studio 3.3; while i'm duplicating the project into another project by changing the package and application id information.

Since the old application is installed on the target device the following 2 options are working

**1. Clean the project and Build it again (Working)**

**2. Uninstall the previous app on the device (Working)**