# Instant run won't work on Android Studio, says Gradle Version 2.10 is required. I use 2.10

Tags: android, gradle, build, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

This is the error I get:

```
Error:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

I use this inside my buildscript:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5'
}
```

This is my gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
#Tue Jan 05 13:28:23 CET 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

As you can see. I use gradle version 2.10.
Do I need to refresh the cache somehow? I Tried clean, rebuild, but nothing works

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need set **Use default gradle wrapper** in

**Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle >Project-level settings**

Comment: I get this now, before installing apk:
Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Split lib_main was defined multiple times

Comment: same to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803518/split-lib-main-was-defined-multiple-times

Comment: Thanks!! I guess instarun is at fault here. Will set this as answered, and disable instarun for now. Thank you

Comment: @adrbtk I use mac and I don't see "Use default gradle wrapper" option  (Project-level settings has no options inside it), do you know what should I change?

Comment: @adrbtk Thanks. I found out it's not under Settings like in Windows, but under Peferences, just like in your screen shot. I opened a question and answered it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990865/android-studio-on-mac-use-default-gradle-wrapper/35012551#35012551

Answer (score 0):

I just changed mine

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5'
}
```

for this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
}
```

For me its working