# Android Studio on Mac - Use default gradle wrapper

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I try to open a new project in Android Studio **on Mac** and get this error:

```
 Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version
```

so I changed
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'` to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5'
```

and then I get this error:

```
Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/.../gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

so I changed it in the gradle-wrapper.properties to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

and still get the same message.

I tried to download 'gradle-2.10' and changed the path in Settings-> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle to the path where 'gradle-2.10' is saved, and still didn't help...

I read that we need to mark the option 'Use default gradle wrapper' in the project-level settings but I don't see options there, only a title...

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it can help someone in the future:

The right path is

*not*

**Settings** → Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Gradle,

but

**Preferences** → Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Gradle