# Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Split null was defined multiple times

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

We are preparing to publish our instant app, however, we are experiencing an issue when attempting to run our AIA app as well as when attempting to upload to the AIA development track in Google Play. This is the first time we are experiencing this issue but have been able to run the AIA in the past. Upon further investigation, it seems as if our base feature apk is somehow being added or referenced multiple times. Any assistance is appreciated.

Android Studio Error:

```
Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Split null was defined multiple times
```

Google Play Error:

```
Your Instant App APKs cannot contain more than one base APK.
```

AIA build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.23.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs '../libs'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildTools


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }

        release {
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions rootProject.flavorDimensions

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            applicationId rootProject.flavor1PackageName
            versionCode rootProject.flavor1VersionCode
            versionName rootProject.flavor1VersionName

            dimension rootProject.flavorDimensions
        }

        flavor2 {
            applicationId rootProject.flavor2PackageName
            versionCode rootProject.flavor2VersionCode
            versionName rootProject.flavor2VersionName

            dimension rootProject.flavorDimensions
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':features:base')
    implementation project(':features:chat')
    implementation project(':features:message')
    implementation project(':features:search')
}
```

base feature build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs '../../libs'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
}

android {

    baseFeature true

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildTools

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {

        flavor1Release {
            storeFile file('../../publish/flavor1-release.keystore')
            storePassword System.getenv("FLAVOR1_STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("FLAVOR1_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("FLAVOR1_KEY_PASSWORD")
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }

        flavor2Release {
            storeFile file('../../publish/flavor2-release.keystore')
            storePassword System.getenv("FLAVOR2_STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("FLAVOR2_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("FLAVOR2_KEY_PASSWORD")
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }

        debug {
            storeFile file('../../publish/debug.keystore')
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions rootProject.flavorDimensions

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            versionCode rootProject.flavor1VersionCode
            versionName rootProject.flavor1VersionName
            dimension rootProject.flavorDimensions
        }

        flavor2 {
            versionCode rootProject.flavor2VersionCode
            versionName rootProject.flavor2VersionName
            dimension rootProject.flavorDimensions
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

        release {
            productFlavors.flavor1.signingConfig signingConfigs.flavor1Release
            productFlavors.flavor2.signingConfig signingConfigs.flavor2Release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    feature project(':features:chat')
    feature project(':features:message')
    feature project(':features:search')
    application project(':app')

    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    api 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    api 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'

    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.2'

    api...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Other feature module build.gradle files (all are the exact same)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs '../../libs'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
}

android {

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildTools

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
    }

    signingConfigs {

        flavor1Release {
            storeFile file('../../publish/flavor1-release.keystore')
            storePassword System.getenv("FLAVOR1_STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("FLAVOR1_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("FLAVOR1_KEY_PASSWORD")
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }

        flavor2Release {
            storeFile file('../../publish/flavor2-release.keystore')
            storePassword System.getenv("FLAVOR2_STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("FLAVOR2_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("FLAVOR2_KEY_PASSWORD")
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }

        debug {
            storeFile file('../../publish/debug.keystore')
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions rootProject.flavorDimensions

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            versionCode rootProject.flavor1VersionCode
            versionName rootProject.flavor1VersionName

            dimension rootProject.flavorDimensions
        }

        flavor2 {
            versionCode rootProject.flavor2VersionCode
            versionName rootProject.flavor2VersionName

            dimension rootProject.flavorDimensions
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

        release {
            productFlavors.flavor1.signingConfig signingConfigs.flavor1Release
            productFlavors.flavor2.signingConfig signingConfigs.flavor2Release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    api project(':features:base')
}
```

After building the split apk artifact, this is the structure after unzipping:

```
aia-release.zip
    - base-release.apk
    - chat-release.apk
    - message-release.apk
    - search-release.apk
```

When inspecting the zip file in Android Studio, everything seems to be correct and in line with the multiple samples Google provides surrounding AIA, multiple features, and multiple flavors.

Additional information:

```
Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2
Gradle plugin: 3.0.0-beta2
Gradle wrapper distribution: 4.1-rc-1
```

**Edit:**

We have managed to identify some more information about the issue. When running the multi-feature sample, the generated artifact has several key components our artifact is missing. However, we are using the same configuration, plugin, etc.

When building any of the sample projects, the generated merged manifests includes the following tags that ours does not.

```
android:isFeatureSplit="true"
split="<name>"
```

However, our merged manifest only adds the tag:

```
featureSplit="<name>"
```

We are still trying to identify why this is occurring and how different our project setup/structure is. But it is a painstaking process as there is limited to no documentation yet around AIA.

More information to follow.

**Edit 2:**

After working more with the project structure, it seems now our base APK resources are not able to be recognized by our feature module manifests. This is specific to the AIA, NOT the regular "Installed" module. When compiling the normal Installed module, this issue does not occur.

Error:

```
No resource found that matches the given name...
```

It is a shame there is no documentation around this as of yet. And we seem to be the only team experiencing these issues.

**Final Edit (SOLVED):**

DO NOT, I repeat, DO NOT have this in your gradle.properties file

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

This is the sole reason for all of the issues we have been experiencing.

Comment: Your two errors may be separate issues. `INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Split null was defined multiple times` may be related to Instant Run (if you have it enabled), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803518/split-lib-main-was-defined-multiple-times. I’ll get back to you later about the base APK issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, it is not an IR issue. I've already tried the suggestion listed in that SO post and it, unfortunately, does not address the issue. We are also on a newer version of the android gradle plugin (3.0.0-beta2). Also, I am able to run the normal application with IR enabled and disabled. I look forward to your reply on the base APK issue.

Comment: Were you able to successfully run your AIA on Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2, or did the issue appear after you updated to Beta 2?

Comment: Is this your first time uploading your AIA to Play Store? If not, were you previously able to upload your AIA without an issue?

Comment: This is the first time we are attempting to upload, yes. However, we have been able to run the aia in the past. But this was before the latest android gradle plugin updates. We've managed to identify some more information which I will add to the post.

Comment: Issue has been resolved. See final edit.