# App Crash in Java [excev]

Tags: java, android, xml

I am running an app which on the click of a button, utilizes VULTR's REST API and sends a post request to the server. However, on the click of the button, the app immediately closes (I am using my telephone, but the same happens on the emulator).

This is the stack trace I receive:

```
11-10 19:11:06.388 32669-32669/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-10 19:11:06.408 32669-32676/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
11-10 19:11:06.515 32669-32669/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.bill.lesdothis-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.bill.lesdothis-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 19:11:06.636 32669-32669/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.bill.lesdothis-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.bill.lesdothis-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 19:11:06.662 32669-32669/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.bill.lesdothis-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.bill.lesdothis-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 19:11:06.685 32669-32669/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.bill.lesdothis-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.bill.lesdothis-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 19:11:06.710 32669-32669/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.bill.lesdothis-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.bill.lesdothis-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 19:11:06.737 32669-32669/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.bill.lesdothis-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.bill.lesdothis-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 19:11:06.760 32669-32669/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.bill.lesdothis-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.bill.lesdothis-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 19:11:06.783 32669-32669/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.bill.lesdothis-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.bill.lesdothis-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 19:11:06.807 32669-32669/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.bill.lesdothis-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.bill.lesdothis-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 19:11:06.831 32669-32669/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.bill.lesdothis-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.sammarriott.lesdothis-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 19:11:06.854 32669-32669/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.bill.lesdothis-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.bill.lesdothis-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-10 19:11:06.855 32669-32669/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.bill.lesdothis-1/lib/arm64
11-10 19:11:06.857 32669-32680/? I/art: Object allocation is busy now, so prior to grow the heap. New heap size is 26 MB
11-10 19:11:06.859 32669-32669/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
11-10 19:11:06.897 32669-32669/? I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
11-10 19:11:06.909 32669-32669/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-10 19:11:07.012 32669-32669/? I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
11-10 19:11:07.034 32669-32680/? I/art: humin current process: com.example.bill.lesdothis
11-10 19:11:07.034 32669-32680/? I/art: current process_level is : 0
11-10 19:11:07.074 32669-32713/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-10 19:12:08.078 32669-1647/com.example.bill.lesdothis I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32669 SIG: 9
```

I have not modified any XML files upon the creation of the files. Here they are:

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sammarriott.lesdothis.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.sammarriott.lesdothis.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infotextview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="nil"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.299" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/apikeyinfobutton"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="API_Key_info"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.031"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.475" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what version of com.android.tools.build:gradle: you use?

Comment: @MilosLulic 2.3.3

Comment: try somethig from this answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803518/split-lib-main-was-defined-multiple-times